# Using SSJS to retrieve info about IsNullable for Data Extension fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I need to copy a Data Extension using SSJS and I believe I can do everything I need to do except understanding if I need to set the fields nullable or not.

I use this code to retrieve the info I need from my existing Data Extension for my new Data Extension:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load('Core','1');
  
var templateDE = DataExtension.Init("AnyDataExtension");
var srcFields = templateDE.Fields.Retrieve();

Write(Stringify(srcFields)+'<br><br>');
```

So far so good, but in my response I see no info about 'nullability'.

This is the response:

```
[{"Name":"GroupName","ObjectID":"f7ff7ff7-41ec-41bd-9132-35ec7b97e4b6","FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":50,"Ordinal":4,"DefaultValue":"","StorageType":"Plain"}, {"Name":"ClaimedDate","ObjectID":"f7ff7ff7-dfd1-427c-9cef-496c73aa96aa","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":3,"DefaultValue":"","StorageType":"Plain"}, {"Name":"ClaimedBy","ObjectID":"f7ff7ff7-e181-4ff3-9daf-82346113a1bb","FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":254,"Ordinal":2,"DefaultValue":"","StorageType":"Plain"}, {"Name":"CouponCode","ObjectID":"f7ff7ff7-1166-44f7-824d-995e886c6fa2","FieldType":"Text","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":50,"Ordinal":0,"DefaultValue":"","StorageType":"Plain"}, {"Name":"IsClaimed","ObjectID":"f7ff7ff7-f502-4488-b278-dde1b04ccf90","FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"MaxLength":0,"Ordinal":1,"DefaultValue":"false","StorageType":"Plain"}]
```

In the following I know that I can actually set a primarykey field nullable or not when preparing the array for my new Data Extension.

I just need to set field.IsRequired = false or true:

```
var fieldsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < srcFields.length; i++) {
 var field = {};

 field.Name = srcFields[i].Name;
 field.FieldType = srcFields[i].FieldType;

 if (srcFields[i].FieldType == 'Text') {
  field.MaxLength = srcFields[i].MaxLength;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].IsPrimaryKey) {
  field.IsPrimaryKey = true;
  field.IsRequired = true;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].DefaultValue) {
  field.DefaultValue = srcFields[i].DefaultValue;
 }
  

 fieldsArray.push(field);

}

Write(Stringify(fieldsArray)+'<br>');
```

But as I have no primarykeys in the Data Extension I'm copying, I need to find another way of finding if the original fields in the Data Extension I'm making a copy of were actually nullable

**Are there ways in SSJS to retrieve info about fields nullable?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if using WSProxy with SSJS, I'm able to get tell if my Data Extension fields are nullable or not.

First of all, SSJS and WSProxy is described nicely and in depth [here](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-data-extensions-in-ssjs/), and from this page I extended my original demo code from this:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load('Core','1');

var templateDE = DataExtension.Init("AnyDataExtension");
var srcFields = templateDE.Fields.Retrieve();

Write(Stringify(srcFields)+'<br><br>');


var fieldsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < srcFields.length; i++) {
 var field = {};

 field.Name = srcFields[i].Name;
 field.FieldType = srcFields[i].FieldType;

 if (srcFields[i].FieldType == 'Text') {
  field.MaxLength = srcFields[i].MaxLength;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].IsPrimaryKey) {
  field.IsPrimaryKey = true;
  field.IsRequired = true;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].DefaultValue) {
  field.DefaultValue = srcFields[i].DefaultValue;
 }

 fieldsArray.push(field);

}

Write('Stringified fieldsArray: '+Stringify(fieldsArray)+'<br>');
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load('Core','1');

var templateDE = DataExtension.Init("AnyDataExtension");
var srcFields = templateDE.Fields.Retrieve();

Write(Stringify(srcFields)+'<br><br>');


var fieldsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < srcFields.length; i++) {
 var field = {};

 field.Name = srcFields[i].Name;
 field.FieldType = srcFields[i].FieldType;

 if (srcFields[i].FieldType == 'Text') {
  field.MaxLength = srcFields[i].MaxLength;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].IsPrimaryKey) {
  field.IsPrimaryKey = true;
  field.IsRequired = true;
 }

 if (srcFields[i].DefaultValue) {
  field.DefaultValue = srcFields[i].DefaultValue;
 }

 fieldsArray.push(field);

}

Write('Stringified fieldsArray: '+Stringify(fieldsArray)+'<br>');




var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

try {

 var dataExtensionName = "AnyDataExtension";

 var req = api.retrieve("DataExtension", ["CustomerKey"], {
  Property: "Name",
  SimpleOperator: "equals",
  Value: dataExtensionName
 });

 var customerKey = req.Results[0].CustomerKey;

 var cols = [
  "Name", 
  "IsRequired"
 ];

 var result = api.retrieve("DataExtensionField", cols, {
  Property: "DataExtension.CustomerKey",
  SimpleOperator: "equals",
  Value: customerKey
 });

 Write('<br>WSProxy, stringified is: '+Stringify(result)+'<br><br>');

} catch(error) {
 Write(Stringify(error));
} 
</script>
```

In the screenshot you can tell, how I now am able to see if ie. the Field named 'IsClaimed' actually is required. With this info I'm now able to make an exact copy of my original Data Extension :)

[image: Code example SSJS and WSProxy]

Answer (score 1):

If you add "field.IsRequired = false;", then the field should become nullable.

Comment: Hi @AndreasDS - you're right. To determine if any of the fields in the new Data Extension can be nullable or not, I can use IsRequired, which is also nicely documented here: [link](https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/contact-builder/dataextensions/create.html)

My bigger headache is still, that I don't know how to retrieve the nullable status of the fields in the original Data Extension, as I want to be able to create an exact copy